# Npm error while installing express js on termux

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been trying to install express js on termux using npm but I get errors

I've tryed using deleting cache on termux and npm but still nothing works!

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOZ82.png)
Here is an image of the error I always get when I try to install it

Comment: Please, provide the error in text, read -> [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

It's talking permissions. This likely means you need super user privilege to execute the command. Try using `sudo npm install express`